# QT the glBegin not declared?

Tags: qt, opengl

i'm following a tutorial to write a small piece of code of opengl in qt.here's the link
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18

but in the 6:13 when I bluid the code it show a couple of error that

```
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp: In member function 'virtual void GLWidget::paintGL()':
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp:17:20: error: 'glColor3f' was not declared in this scope
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp:19:25: error: 'glBegin' was not declared in this scope
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp:20:31: error: 'glVertex3f' was not declared in this scope
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp:23:11: error: 'glEnd' was not declared in this scope
..\testopgl\glwidget.cpp: At global scope:
```

what I really don't understand is when I only put the glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) it builds alright,but occurs error even i just put the glColor3f().Does the GLWidget not support the glColor*() or glBegin() command?

here's my code.

testopgl.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-28T09:48:44
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testopgl
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

glwidget.h

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w,int h);
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

glwidget.cpp

```
#include "glwidget.h"


GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(1,1,0,1);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glColor3f(1,0,0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0);
    glEnd();


}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w,int h){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you mention are simply not present in any modern version of GL, so the tutorial you are following sounds like it is quite out of date.

So probably the version of GL exposed through your build of QT does not have these functions. It may be possible to reconfigure/rebuild QT to use an older version of GL, but I would instead recommend getting to know and use the modern programmable interface.

Comment: thanks JasonD.I found another tutorial and it also said the same as you said.